# Day of week function not working

Tags: java, algorithm, dayofweek

I'm trying to create a function where given a year where `year > 1999` and it returns a value 0 through 6 where `Sunday = 0, Monday = 1 ... Saturday = 6` that corresponds to the day of the week that the first day of November is on. Since I know November 1, 2000 is 3 (Wednesday) I use that as `NOV1`. I know I have to keep leap years in mind so I have an `if` statement that will help. I don't know why it doesn't work properly for years greater than 2100. Help!

```
public static int firstOfMonth(int year)
{
  int raw = year - 2000;
  int leapYears = raw / 4;
  int nonLeapYears = 0;
  if ( raw >= 100 )
  {
    nonLeapYears = raw / 100;
    leapYears = leapYears - ( nonLeapYears - ( nonLeapYears / 4 ) );
  }
  else
  {
    nonLeapYears = 0;
  }
  return ((( NOV1 + ( raw * 365 ) - leapYears) ) % 7 );
}
```

again, NOV1 = 3

Comment: Dates and times are incredibly complex constructs to program. Generally, it's better to use the Java `Calendar` API.

Comment: Generally, its better to use something like joda time than the incredibly poorly designed calendar api.

Comment: @christopher It's never a good idea to use the `Calendar` API, it's a terrible API. Java8 got `java.time`, and there is also joda-time that you can use if you run earlier jre

Comment: I need it to be a custom designed thing though. No APIs.

Comment: I sincerely apologise! I wrote the comment half mindedly. As @amit suggested, use Joda time or `java.time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to occur because you are subtracting leap years in your return statement rather than adding them.

---

Part of the reason errors like this can occur and be so hard to notice is when the surrounding code becomes overly complicated.  It's easier to see what was going wrong when you simplify the code.

For instance, this entire block of code:

```
int leapYears = raw / 4;
int nonLeapYears = 0;    
if ( raw >= 100 )
  {
    nonLeapYears = raw / 100;
    leapYears = leapYears - ( nonLeapYears - ( nonLeapYears / 4 ) );
  }
  else
  {
    nonLeapYears = 0;
  }
```

Can all be simplified to:

```
int leapYears = int(raw/4) - int(raw/100) + int(raw/400);
```

That's every fourth year minus years divisible by 100 except years also divisible by 400.  Make sense?
Once you have the number of leap years that have passed, calculating the number of days since Nov 1, 2000 should be as simple as:

```
365 * raw + leapYears;
```

You have to add as many extra days are there are leap years, since a leap year has 366 days.  Therefore, your return statement should be:

```
return ( NOV1 + 365 * raw + leapYears ) % 7;
```

In the end, you should have something like this:

```
public static int firstOfMonth(int year)
{
    int raw = year - 2000;
    int leapYears = int(raw/4) - int(raw/100) + int(raw/400);
    return ( NOV1 + 365 * raw + leapYears ) % 7;
}
```

Comment: Does that answer the question? Does it solve the actual problem the OP raised? If so - please elaborate where and how. Or is it just "code beautification"?

Comment: And on the "code beautification" note: Fewer lines of code != cleaner/more readable/better code in all cases.

Comment: Thanks! My code tends to be terribly unclear, and this helped a ton!

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear what the OP had done incorrectly.  This isn't a matter of beautification.  Many times, bugs like this are much easier to find when their containing logic is more straightforward. My goal here was to not only point out the problem but also show how I discovered it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works up to year 2400. You need a check to see if the year is divisible by 400 - then it's a leap year...